# Why does my solution not work in LeetCode?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, merge

You are given two integer arrays nums1 and nums2, sorted in non-decreasing order, and two integers m and n, representing the number of elements in nums1 and nums2 respectively.

Merge nums1 and nums2 into a single array sorted in non-decreasing order.

**Example 1**

**Input**: nums1 = [1,2,3,0,0,0], m = 3, nums2 = [2,5,6], n = 3

**Output**: [1,2,2,3,5,6]

**Explanation**: The arrays we are merging are [1,2,3] and [2,5,6].
The result of the merge is [1,2,2,3,5,6] with the underlined elements coming from nums1.

```
function merge(nums1, m, nums2, n) {
    let looped = nums1.map((e) => {
        return e;
    })
    let numbers = looped.splice(nums1.length - n, m);
    let merged = numbers.concat(nums2);

    return merged.sort(((a, b) => {
        return a - b;
      }));
    };
merge([1,2,3,0,0,0], 3 , [2,5,6],3)
```

Expect Output:

[1,2,2,3,5,6]

[1]

[1]

My Output:

[1,2,3,0,0,0]

[1]

[0]

Comment: Why are there `0's` in the example? Typo?

Comment: What is the error it gives on leetcode? Is it "Memory error", like `Segmentation Fault` or "Timeout error"?

Comment: I hope this working solution helps you. I will delete this answer in next 24 hours, as I don't really understand the downvotes on a working solution. BTW, this was my 1st submission on Leetcode too, so thanks for that :)